# Additive Gaussian Noise

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, matrix-calculus

Suppose we have a 2-d matrix $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, it could be some signal, or an image let's say.

Suppose we have this noise model: $N(\mu=0,\sigma=1)$.

If we compute: 
 $K=Z + N(\mu=0, \sigma=1)$ 
and then 
 $L = K+ N(\mu=0,\sigma=2)$. 
 Can we say that the total noise on $L$ is $N(\mu=0,\sigma=3)$ ?

What exactly is additive on this noise?

Comment: What does $\sigma$ refer to for you, the standard deviation of the noise? If so, you want to be careful in the adding, since it is the *variances* that add up (when summing independent normal random variables), not the standard deviations.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth yeah $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. So we will have total $\sigma^{2}$=5 in this example but sqrt(5) standard deviation?

Comment: Correct! The standard deviation would be $\sqrt{5}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additive property of a noise is called so because the noise is get added to the signal. For example if we denote the input signal by $s$, the noise by $v$ and the output signal by $y$ and assume that the noise is additive, then $$y=s+v$$ in which $y,s,v$ could be matrices, vectors, scalars or higher order tensors. One prominent example of such kind of noises is [AWGN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise)
.

Now, by substitution we can write  $$L=Z+N(\mu=0,\sigma^2=1)+N(\mu=0,\sigma^2=4)$$a mathematical theorem states that the summation of two independent Gaussian random variable with the same average, is also a Gaussian random variable with its variance being the summation of the other two variances. In our case, we can write $$L=Z+N(\mu=0,\sigma^2=5)$$